# Proving $\sinh{x}$ is strictly increasing over all the reals and $\cosh{x}$ is strictly decreasing on $(- \infty , 0]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, hyperbolic-functions

How would I be proving $\sinh{x}$ is strictly increasing and $\cosh{x}$ is strictly decreasing on $(- \infty , 0]$

I succeded in showing $\cosh{x}$ is strictly increasing on the interval $[0, \infty)$ but having trouble with the rest. The $\sinh$ one is really messing with me.

*I can not use derivatives. I know how to but am not allowed - for some reason.

Comment: Do you have the definition (or theorem) relating $\sinh$ to exponential functions (which are always positive)?

Comment: I have the definitions of the functions, yes.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

For any real $ x$,

$$S(x)=\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$

is the sum of two strictly increasing functions.

Comment: I can not use derivatives. Should specify. Will add this now.

Comment: @mathstudent23 I edited. the sum of two increasing functions is increasing.

Comment: But even in that case; That does not prove for **strictly** increasing only that it is increasing.

Comment: @mathstudent23 The sum of two strictly increasing .....

Comment: That is still not satisfying. I know that these are strictly increasing but that has to be shown otherwise I am just postulating this.

Comment: @mathstudent23 $x<y\implies e^x<e^y$

Comment: May depend on how you define $e^x$; can probably get it from the fact that the power series for positive $x$ has all positive coefficients and $e^x e^{-x} = 1$ or more general applications of the addition formula for $e^x$.

Comment: @leslietownes This is a part of a analysis class. I think the method that is wanted is to use the addition formulas i.e $\cosh(x+y)=...$

Comment: Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148872/show-that-sinh-x-is-strictly-increasing will help.